# iOS SDWebImage for UITableView？

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

This is my code,I have created a cusom UITableViewCell and uses SDWebImage to load image asynchronously. But it is not working. When I use default cell like this "cell.imageView setImage..." it works fine,I don't know why?

```
DiscoutCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
[cell.goodsImageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"zanwutupian.png"]];
```

Comment: Can you let us know how you are initializing the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method? If you are using "xib", you should load the xib from bundle.

Comment: if (!nibsRegistered) {
        UINib *nib  = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"DiscoutCell" bundle:nil];
        [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        nibsRegistered = YES;
    }

Comment: I also have some label to be displayed in the cell and it is ok.The only problem is the image

Comment: It may sound silly, did you connect the IBOutlet of imageView?

Comment: Is the placeholder image visible?

Comment: Maybe there is something error with the image url. Does the url works?

Comment: NO,even the placeholder image is not visible,I think the problem is that imageview,but I just don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Solved I find I don't link that imageView to my IBOutet imageview,I'm so sorry for wasting your time,it's my fault.I'm so careless!Anyway,thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved
I find I don't link that imageView to my IBOutet imageview,I'm so sorry for wasting your time,it's my fault.I'm so careless!Anyway,thanks very much!